# Determine, if a value is jumping between two prices or if it's actually evolving

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I made a personal webtool that collects data about price changes in a plotly graph. The prices are being fed into my script via websocket every 20 seconds. As of now, every change in price will create a new point on the graph. This works fine!

**Problem**:
Most items get an actual price update every 1-2 hours, but some seem to be jittering by a few cents. This means, that an item could go from 1.50€ to 1.51€ and back every 20 seconds for hours, creating endless graph points. The data from the websocket will always contain a full pricelist for a few hundred items - even if their prices didn't change.

My approach on this seems to work partially. I am saving the last two known prices in a short array with each item. If the price changes, it will check, if the last two changes included this new price, if so: No new point, just update the old one. If the new price is not included in the "blacklist" array (so a "real" price change), generate a new point and update the blacklist array accordingly. The problem is, that if an item starts to jitter again after a "real" update, it will generate a tiny spike with an additional point.

Is there any smarter way of doing this, without errors?

```
var db = { // Example object in my database
    apple: {currentPrice: 1.44, graphX: [1.42, 1.41, 1.44], graphY: [1534175049283, 1534175019374, 1534175082191], blackList = [1.44, 1.41]}
}

function newPrice(name, price){
    if(db[name].currentPrice != price){ // Check if the price changed at all
        if(db[name].blackList.indexOf(.price) == -1){ // Check if the price has been seen within the last 2 changes, if not, treat it as a new price
            db[name].graphX.push(price); // Add price...
            db[name].graphY.push(Date.now()); // ...and timestamp to X and Y arrays for a plotly graph to read when requested
            db[name].currentPrice = price; // Update the current price (for easier access)
            db[name].blackList[1] = db[name].blackList[0]; // Move the blacklist array by one up, delete the oldest one
            db[name].blackList[0] = price; // set the new price to [0] on the blacklist
            console.log("New graph point created!")
        } else { // If it's one of the recent prices, dont add a new graph point, just update the old one 
            db[name].currentPrice = price; // Update the current price (for easier access)
            db[name].graphX[db[name].graphX.length - 1] = price; // update the last array segment (price)
            db[name].graphY[db[name].graphY.length - 1] = Date.now(); // update the last array segment (time)
            console.log("Jittering price, updated last graph point!");
        }
    }
}

newPrice("apple", 1.41) // Gets called by a websocket every ~30 seconds, providing a name and a price
```

Comment: Unless you say something like changes within a certain % or value of current are ignored, then no you can't do this.  In the case you mention of jittering after a real update - if neither of the "jitter prices" are in the blacklist then they are both valid and should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If the actual price doesn't update except for every hour or so, why not have it run every hour instead of every 20 seconds or so? Consider looking into options on how to run your script on a set interval.

See: [Running a node.js script every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461132/running-a-node-js-script-every-10-seconds)
and edit to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a change tolerance limit, let's call it L. If |newValue - oldValue| <= L, then you consider the change to be too minuscule and ignore it. Also, you will need a maximal unchanged limit, called MU, so, if there were MU values since the last unignored change, then you plot the new change anyway. This would make the graph much more stable and easier to study.